# How to make popouts with CTkInput encode

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm working on password manager and had structure like that:

```
def popUp(text):
    answer = simpledialocusg.askstring("input string", text)

    return answer
```

And it works perfectly, but I want to make popouts looks better with Custom Tkinter. When I made

```
def popUp(text):
    answer = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog("input string", text)

    return answer
```

I got an error:
`AttributeError: 'CTkInputDialog' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Expect popouts works correctly

Comment: Cannot reproduce the mentioned exception when running the code.  It is better to provide a [mre].  Also suggest to look at example in official document on [CTkInputDialog](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkInputDialog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the wiki page before opening a question here.

https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkInputDialog

The syntax should be like this:

```
def getInput():
    answer = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text = "input string")
    print(answer.get_input())

root = customtkinter.CTk()

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, command=getInput)
button.pack(pady=30, padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank for your help so much. I'm just learning, next time will read docs better <3